# How do I get this Django CSS to render properly in my production environment?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am trying to deploy a Django application in a production environment and I can't seem to get the CSS to render properly. In my local environment it works fine. In the settings, I have set up:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

On the server I've run collectstatic to gather the files into the following folder:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/sites/thetweethereafter.com/public/static'
```

The webserver is nginx, and my nginx.conf is:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.thetweethereafter.com;
      rewrite ^/(.*) http://thetweethereafter.com/$1 permanent;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name thetweethereafter.com;

      access_log /sites/thetweethereafter.com/logs/access.log;
      error_log /sites/thetweethereafter.com/logs/error.log;

      location /static {
          autoindex on;
          root /sites/thetweethereafter.com/public/;
      }

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:29000;
      }
    }
}
```

If I browse directly to the static files, I can get them no problem.

http://thetweethereafter.com/static/css/styles.css

However, when I load a page that references one of these files, the browser is not rendering them.

http://thetweethereafter.com

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have lots of other projects set up in a similar way and they work fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Looking at your website index, the css files are served as "text/plain" by nginx. Maybe that is a nginx misconfiguration ?

Comment: Can you post your entire nginx conf?

Comment: I've updated with the entire nginx conf.

Comment: @Bathz, yes you're right, but I've looked in the mime.types file and see the correct mime type in there: `text/html html htm shtml; text/css css;` etc...

Comment: @JamieForrest double check that the mime.types file is included in the http section : `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` ?

Comment: @Bathz If you add an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspecting your website index I noticed the css files are served as "text/plain" instead of "text/css" file type. So the problem should rely in the server configuration.

Nginx has to know which mime type apply according to the file extension. On a fresh debian install there is an include directive in the http section like this :

```
http {
[...]
   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
[...]
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem before. To solve it for CSS and other external static files:

1. Edit your mime.types file (or create one if it doesn't exist). (Your mime.types file is probably located in /etc/nginx/)
2. Copy and paste this in (quoting from from http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample):

   `types {
       text/html                             html htm shtml;
       text/css                              css;
       text/xml                              xml rss;
       image/gif                             gif;
       image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
       application/x-javascript              js;
       text/plain                            txt;
       text/x-component                      htc;
       text/mathml                           mml;
       image/png                             png;
       image/x-icon                          ico;
       image/x-jng                           jng;
       image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
       application/java-archive              jar war ear;
       application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
       application/pdf                       pdf;
       application/x-cocoa                   cco;
       application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
       application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
       application/x-makeself                run;
       application/x-perl                    pl pm;
       application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
       application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
       application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
       application/x-sea                     sea;
       application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
       application/x-stuffit                 sit;
       application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
       application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
       application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
       application/zip                       zip;
       application/octet-stream              deb;
       application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
       application/octet-stream              dmg;
       application/octet-stream              eot;
       application/octet-stream              iso img;
       application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;
       audio/mpeg                            mp3;
       audio/x-realaudio                     ra;
       video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
       video/quicktime                       mov;
       video/x-flv                           flv;
       video/x-msvideo                       avi;
       video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
       video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
       video/x-mng                           mng;
   }`
3. Next, insert inside the http section of the nginx.conf file (located in /etc/nginx/):

   `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` (or whatever path leads to your mime.types file)
4. Finally, reload nginx.conf by entering on the command line:

   `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload`
5. I would also restart nginx:

   sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart

EDIT: I don't know why my code snippet above is formatted so wacky. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `location /static` rule is before the `location /` rule in your nginx conf. Here's mine for example:

```
server {

        listen   81; ## listen for ipv4

        server_name  172.27.111.152;
        root /opt/projects/msv/www;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/msv.access.log;

        location /static {
                root /opt/projects/msv/www;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mov) {
               access_log   off;
               expires      30d;
        }
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3002;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Please see above with full nginx.conf file.